# ADB not recognising Nexus 4 - more advice

Tags: android, mobile, nexus-4

Following on from [ADB not recognising Nexus 4 under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005176/adb-not-recognising-nexus-4) I am having problems getting the Eclipse android development environment to recognise my new Nexus 4. My privious Nexus S had no problems.

I believe I have followed all the advice in this previous post but am still stuck.

Can anybody who has succeeded getting the nexus 4 available for android development on windows 7, tell me what their driver detail are for the "Android Composite ABD Interface"? Mine say: 
 * Driver Provider: "Google Inc" 
 * Driver Date: 27/08/12 
 * Driver Version: 7.0.0.1

When my phone storage is set to either PTP or MTP, I still can't see it through the eclipse "android virtual device manager".

When set to PTP, if I run the "adb devices" command described in the linked article, I do get an entry appearing in the dos box, but nothing in the "android virtual device manager" in eclipse.

Comment: I haven't installed on win7. But I think you can install driver from ask the place you can download avid image file.

Comment: Probably you did, but did you turn on USB logging, on your device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Nexus 4 isn't a virtual device, so won't show in Virtual Devices Manager.

If you open the Devices view, then you should see your Nexus 4 listed, and when you run your app it should prompt for running it on as physical or virtual device.

Comment: Ahh. I've been trying so long, I had missed that completely! I can see the phone in the devices view if I put it into PTP mode, which although that isn't ideal, it will suffice.  Many thanks

Comment: Removing and reinstalling the driver may deal with the PTP issue.

Answer (score 17):

The solution is to connect your device with PTP instead of MTP and, it works.
Connected devices are not visible in AVD manager. AVD manager is for emulators.
To show connected devices, you use only ADB with this command :

```
adb devices
```

Comment: That also did the trick for me. 1. Switch to PTP, 2. go through this process: (http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/2/) 3.authorize device 4. works

Answer (score 4):

This is great step by step tutor for it:
http://androidsecurity.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/install-google-nexus-4-adb-usb-drivers-on-windows-android-studio/

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the device driver completely from Windows and re-install it.

Comment: This worked for me. Upon upgrading to Windows 8.1 my Nexus 4 no longer appeared in 'adb devices'. I uninstalled the device in Device Manager, and made sure to check "delete driver". I then attached the Nexus 4 and windows installed the correct driver. I now see it in 'adb devices'.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont see the device in the Devices lists:

First, you need to make sure USB debugging is enabled on your device. Settings->DeveloperOptions: Turn on debugging and enable USB debugging. Ideally, you will install the USB drivers from google, and it will work fine: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver. There are some cases that new installation may mess up the device connection. You may want to try these:

1. It may lost the connection, so you can try:

> ```
>      adb kill-server
>      adb start-server 
>      adb devices
> ```

1. Updating to new tools may mess up the settings:
   Go to Storage Options and try to set as Media(MTP) or Camera(PTP) connection. Swtiching to one of them will help
2. Revoke authorizations, disable usb debugging and then enable