# ADB Driver and Windows 8.1

Tags: android, windows, driver, adb, windows-8.1

I waste a lot of time trying to successfully install the ADB driver for my tablet in Windows 8.1. So here I will post what I did, in case anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Post with images ➤ [English Version](https://ivanrf.com/en/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1/) | [Versión en Español](https://ivanrf.com/adb-driver-y-windows-8-1/)

---

If Windows fails to enumerate the device which is reported in Device Manager as **error code 43**:

- Install this [Compatibility update](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2917929) from Windows.
- If you already have this update but you get this error, restart your PC (unfortunately, it happened to me, I tried everything until I thought what if I restart...).

If the device is listed in Device Manager as Other devices -> Android but reports an **error code 28**:

- [Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) didn't work for me. You could try your corresponding [OEM USB Drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers), but in my case my device is not listed there.
- So, install the latest Samsung drivers: [SAMSUNG USB Driver v1.7.23.0](https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html)
- Restart the computer (**very important**)
- Go to Device Manager, find the Android device, and select *Update Driver Software*.
- Select *Browse my computer for driver software*
- Select *Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer*
- Select **ADB Interface** from the list
- Select **SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface** (this is a signed driver). If you get a warning, select *Yes* to continue.
- Done!

By doing this I was able to use my tablet for development under Windows 8.1.

**Note:** This solution uses Samsung drivers but **works for other devices**.

Post with images => [English Version](https://ivanrf.com/en/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1/) | [Versión en Español](https://ivanrf.com/adb-driver-y-windows-8-1/)

Comment: I'm assuming you were using a Samsung device which is why you are using the Samsung drivers. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: No, it's not. I use Samsung drivers since it was the only way to make my device work under Win 8.1. I'm actually using an Ainol tablet.

Comment: cool, used the Samsung driver for a generic android device and am able to connect and debug. Thanks so much for your tip!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day, i tried several solution nothing worked except this one, thanks once again.

Comment: After 6 -7 hrs of research, this fix was perfect !! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Thank you, I can finally use ADB! Just a note, if you've already installed the Google ADB driver for your device, you have to uninstall it before following these instructions, or the Samsung driver won't show up.

Comment: I have an issue where my device (Samsung SM-T110 with USB debugging turned on) appears under "Portable Devices", but does not appear in "Other devices" so I can't update the drivers of the unknown device. http://imgur.com/9TQTTJe My 2 other devices work fine

Comment: Followed the steps, added the folders to my system path. Still can't use ADB. F*ck this OS!

Comment: Thanks, even though there was no OEM Driver for my LG Fuel (LGL34C) the OEM driver for other version worked. It seems in the case of LG they make a generic driver for some of their phones.

Comment: IvanRF you deserve some beer, I think :)

Comment: @IvanRF Thank you so much buddy. You saved my day. It was just a ADB driver which didn't show my device on android studio.

Comment: the link to obtain the last drivers has to be updated [link] (http://download1405.mediafire.com/y2d30my9pchg/7peooq05qfaawxq/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe)
Working for my samsung GT-I90601, thanks !

Comment: Just do what he says using samsung driver! It will work with windows 8.1 !!

Comment: @Yogesh Seriously! 6-7 hours of research!?  That is just unacceptable.

Comment: Works with my Bq Edison 2 Quad Core + Windows 8.1

Comment: Success with my Sony SmartWatch 3

Comment: Thank you! i never used the Samsung Drivers... Infact what worked for me was the step where you mentioned "Select Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
Select ADB Interface from the list" - this was the solution, and i just selected my latest google usb drivers i had downloaded.

Comment: Worked Fine for my Huawei Honor 4C.

Comment: For the record, this saved my life, I use a Dell Laptop with an AMD processor, do not support virtual device, so I decided to do it on my phone, buty I have a *Amazon Fire Phone*, thanks to this I finally made my phone available for testing!

Comment: thanks, worked for Xiaomi, Lenovo, etc, using that Samsung driver

Comment: Worked for Proscan tablet PLT7650G. The tablet was correctly identified before this fix. As such, I didn't update the driver for the Android device itself. Instead, I updated the driver for the item "Other device->?unknown" (might not have been "unknown", specifically, but cannot remember). After the fix, in Device Manager (DM) it shows as "ADB Interface ->SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface". Further down in that DM list, the item "Portable Devices->PLT7650G" still exists. All working. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Use the awesome "Universal ADB (Android Debug Bridge) Driver for Windows":
https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH
https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

- Windows 8 compatible
- comes signed, so does not require you to turn off windows driver signature checks

Tested under Win8.1.1 x64.

Comment: I try a lot of stuff but that driver solve my issues. Big Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. Can confirm. Worked out of the box on Windows 8.1. Using it to connect to a stock Nexus 4.

Comment: Oh boy. Why the hell can clockworkmod do what Intel & Google still fail to do? Provide a simple, universal adb&fastboot driver. That's what we need. Thanks for the hint. Confirmed to be working on Win8.1 with Nexus 4 where Google USB driver and Intel Android Driver failed (when device was in recovery mode). Used it to push Android 5 OTA files using sideload. So adb sideload confirmed aswell.

Comment: ok, so it installed something under Program Files (x86), now what? Do I need to restart?  Try to install the driver from Device Manager?  Something else?

Answer (score 4):

There is lots of stuff on this topic, each slightly different. Like many users I spent hours trying them and got nowhere. In the end, this is what worked for me - I.e. installed the driver on windows 8.1

In my extras/google/usb_driver is a file android_winusb.inf

I double clicked on this and it "ran" and installed the driver.

I can't explain why this worked.

Comment: I had to right click the inf file and click "install" - but as soon as I did, my Nexus 6P and ADB immediately connected, and the phone prompted me for authorization. Yay!

Answer (score 4):

I had the following problem: 
I had a Android phone without drivers, and it could not be recognized by the Windows 8.1. Neither as phone, neither as USB storage device.

I searched Device manager.
I opened Device manager, I right click on Android Phone->Android Composite Interface.
I selected "Update Driver Software"
I choose "Browse My Computer for Driver Software"
Then I choose "Let me pick from a list of devices"
I selected "USB Composite Device"

A new USB device is added to the list, and I can connect to my phone using adb and Android SDK.

Also I can use the phone as storage device.
Good luck

Comment: This solved it for me, as well. It took several attempts before I realized I was supposed to choose the composite driver -- I kept selecting the one with ABD in the name despite the fact these instructions said *not* to do that. Once I chose the generic USB Composite Device driver all was well.

Answer (score 2):

http://adbdriver.com/

this worked for me, in my latest Micromax Yu Yuphoria!
just download the installer and install it

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too when nothing else suggested here did.

Comment: Amazing.. This worked fully.. got my phone both reconised in device manager (under portable devices as it should be), and got adb devices to work. Funnily enough the driver from motorola only did the former. But this really worked.

Answer (score 2):

The most complete answer I have found is here:
http://blog.kikicode.com/2013/10/installing-android-adb-driver-in.html

I'm copying the complete answer below.

---

## Installing Android ADB driver in Windows 8.1 64-bit when all else fails

For some reason I just couldn't get my machine to recognize Xperia J in Windows 8.1 64-bit. Even after installing latest Sony PC Companion (2.10.174).  Device Manager kept showing yellow exclamation mark to an 'Android'.

Here's the solution, but I don't promise it will work on your device!

### 1. Find out your device's VID and PID

Open Device Manager, right-click that Android with yellow exclamation mark and click Properties.
Go to Details tab.
In Property, select Hardware Ids.
Right-click the value and click Copy.
Paste the value somewhere.

### 2. Download Android USB Driver

Run Android SDK Manager.
Expand Extras, tick Google USB Driver, click Install packages.
After installation, look for the driver location by hovering mouse over Google USB Driver. The location will appear in the tooltip.

### 3. Modify android_winusb.inf

Go to the usb driver location, for example in the above picture it is c:\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
Make a backup copy of android_winusb.inf
Open android_winusb.inf with a text editor. Notepad is fine but Notepad++ is better, it will syntax highlight the inf file!
Look for [Google.NTx86], and insert a line with your device's hardware ID that you copied above, for example

```
[Google.NTx86]

; ... other existing lines

;SONY Sony Xperia J
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_6188&MI_01
```

Look for [Google.NTamd86], and insert the same lines, for example:

```
[Google.NTamd64]

; ... other existing lines

;SONY Sony Xperia J
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_6188&MI_01
```

Save the file.

### 4. Disable driver signing

Run Command Prompt as an administrator
Paste and run the following commands:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Restart Windows.

### 5. Install driver

Open Device Manager, right-click that Android with yellow exclamation mark and click Update Driver Software.
Click Browse my computer for driver software.
Enter or browse to the folder containing android_winusb.inf, eg: C:\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
Click Next.
The driver will install.
Run adb devices to confirm your device is working fine.

### 6. Re-enable driver signing

Run Command Prompt as an administrator
Paste and run the following commands:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

Restart Windows.
Run adb devices to reconfirm!

Comment: This is the one which works for me, as Koushik's inf does not include the Pixel C. I also had to disable UEFI's Secure boot to be able to run the second 'TESTSIGNING' command. I used this guide for win8.1: https://itsfoss.com/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, 8 or 8.1, in Devices Manager:

1. Select tree 'Android Device': remove 'Android Composite ADB Interface' [х]
2. Press on main root of devices tree and call context menu (by right mouse click) and click on 'Update configuration'
3. After updating your device should appear in 'Other devices'
4. Select your device, call context menu from it and choose 'Update driver' and perform this updating

Answer (score 0):

If all other solutions did not work for your device try this [guide how to make a truly universal adb and fastboot driver](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html) out of [Google USB driver](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip). The resulting driver works for `adb`, `recovery` and `fastboot` modes in all versions of Windows.