# Android Studio Does Not Recognize my Galaxy Core LTE?

Tags: android, android-studio

Simply put, my Samsung Galaxy Core LTE is plugged in via USB, but is not listed by Android Studio as a running device.

I've done some Googling to try to find a driver or something to fix my problem, but nothing. I also can't emulate the Galaxy Core LTE device in Android Studio. Anything I can do?

Comment: The obvious question, did you enable developer options in your device settings? Question number two... Open device manager if you see any yellow warning signs?

Comment: Developer Options are enabled. For the curious, for my model, you have to tap "Build Number" 7 times in order to get the message that it has been enabled, there is not an explicit setting.

Comment: Of course there is. Go to settings -> Developer Options -> USB debugging checkbox

Comment: Ahhh - my mistake. That, coupled with authentication from the mobile device itself, solved my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Ok. I have added an answer below for the rest of the people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, you did this to solve your problem

- Enable USB Debugging via Settings -> Developer Options -> Set USB Debugging checkbox to true
- Authorize PC to access your device

Answer (score 0):

**Have you enabled your USB Debugging?**

If not then go to Setting>>Developer Option and enable it.

**Download** the *adb driver* from [here](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_143128870051610&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=i9iwboaf01000n4o000DAee69wiek&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fgalaxy-core%2Fhelp%2Fsamsung-galaxy-core-lte-sm-g386f-t2861684&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.samsung.com%2Fboard%2Fdownload.do%3FbdId%3D0000000700%26attachId%3D0000000001&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.bd%2F&title=Samsung%20General%20Galaxy%20Core%20LTE%20SM-G386F%20kno%E2%80%A6%20%7C%20Samsung%20Galaxy%20Core%20%7C%20XDA%20Forums&txt=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.samsung.com%2Fboard%2Fd...hId%3D0000000001) for samsung.

Install it. If you are using windows 8.1 and still having the issue then just follow [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21972659/1276495).

It should work.