# Android Studio is not showing adb device in list

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed the and adb driver on my android device which is yu-yuphoria
now in device manager my device is listed as android adb interface . But when i run any app on android studio that device is not listed . I  have changed the usb mode from media to camera again installed the adb interface and restarted both system and device still the device is not listed in android studio.
i have spend hours in fixing the problem but cannot do.
few days earlier there was no such problem but now it came from no where
any possible solution

Comment: Take a look at Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration. If this is enabled, you might want to go to the Developer Options on the device and revoke the authorisation for USB Debugging. Then grant it again. it's all a longshot

Comment: it is enabled and developer mode is active and usb debugging  is on still the device is not listed

Comment: Do emulators or other devices show up, if you have any?

Comment: if i run emulator then it shows up

Comment: but not the external android device

Comment: Maybe it's usb problem? can you detect your device?

Comment: yes i can detect it's is listed in device manager under android as android adb interface

Answer (score 3):

I had all those weird problems with Windows showing perfect configuration but devices not visible. With three different phones, I always fixed it with this free tool (from XDA I believe):

http://adbdriver.com/

Ofcourse this will not help if it is actually a problem with Android Studio.

Comment: Perhaps try uninstalling them? Via the device manager. Then reinstall. Keep the device in MTP mode.

Comment: The driver installer? Run in compatibility mode for windows 7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows

Comment: the driver installer is running but when i try to install driver on my device then that error comes up

Comment: I see, that is difficult. And phone is in MTP mode? Did you try camera mode as well when running the driver installer? If both fail, then I have no ideas, sorry :(

Comment: i have tried both
if i switch to ubuntu will i face such problems of drivers

Comment: I have no experience with Ubuntu, sorry.

Comment: Here is a similar problem I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972658/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1