# Samsung A5 USB issue

Tags: samsung-mobile

My Samsung A5 doesn't connect any laptop through USB. What is happening with my phone? My android version is above 5.0. I have followed a lot of solutions online. I tried using samsung kies but yet still it won't work.

Comment: Have you tried using ADB? What OS is your laptop running?

Comment: Try asking at http://superuser.com/ . That is a sister site to stackoverflow which is better suited for general computing questions. When you do it would help if you listed out the solutions you already tried

Comment: @HomerPlata   i am running on windows 8.1.. i also have mac  Os Seria.. It doesn't run on any of them.  My friends also use Windows 10 and it doesn't work on any.  I have tried ADB, restarted my machine and it doesn't still work

Comment: When you say you have tried ADB but it doesn't work, what exactly have you tried? If adb is installed and running properly, connect your device via USB to your Mac, open a terminal and type _adb shell_. That should give you a command line interface to your device. If this doesn't work, can you tell me what the error says?

Comment: @HomerPlata How do i run the adb on my windows. i don't have my mac at the moment please.  I have installed it on my windows

Comment: I haven't used ADB on the Windows command line, so I can't speak from experience, but this StackOverflow question should help you set it up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972658/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1