# ADT Eclipse not recognising Nexus 7 (and may be other devices) for debugging under Windows 8

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8.1, eclipse-adt

ADT Eclipse not recognising Nexus 7 (and may be other devices) for debugging under Windows 8.

Any solution?

Comment: have you enable debugging mode??

Comment: that's the first thing i did.

Comment: have you install the drivers??

Comment: yes, I have tried multiple solutions to this problem, i already did all the basic stuff.

Comment: Found the solution here; http://stackoverflow.com/a/14009570/3464341. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB not recognising Nexus 4 under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005176/adb-not-recognising-nexus-4-under-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

The Google USB Driver is required for Windows only in order to perform adb debugging with any of the Google Nexus devices. The one exception is the Galaxy Nexus: the driver for Galaxy Nexus is distributed by Samsung (listed as model SCH-I515).

[Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)