# Running android application on device, device not found

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using windows 8. I am trying to run the application on device my device is not found, device USB debugging is enabled. Also, I have installed the drivers for the same using manage 
also I have installed the Google USB driver package.
Still, device is not found.

Please, can anybody help

Comment: Probably USB drive is not installed correctly. Have you tried to reinstall it as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15960179/1028256

Comment: Try the commands as I given below

Comment: tried even that too.. still my device not found

Comment: possible duplicate of [Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable)

Comment: I faced this problem just now and for that I just restart my system and problem get solved

Answer (score 2):

Kill the adb.exe with a command prompt. For this, open command prompt and go to the directory where your adb.exe is located and then type following commands

```
1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server
3. adb devices

May this will help you
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have [USB degugging](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-enable-USB-debugging-on-Android_id53909) enabled on your device. If not, please enable it and reconnect device.

Please type `adb devices` into command line (first go to folder where you have adb installed) to verify that device connected. If not, it's probably a driver issue.